# Updating column values in data.table, based on column values

Tags: r, data.table

Consider the below code :

```
library(data.table) 
dataT <-data.table(1:15,runif(15),runif(15),runif(15))

for(vrb in names(dataT)) {
  dataT[get(vrb) < 0.5, (vrb):=0.5] # update value
}
```

As can be inferred from the code, I am basically capping the lowest value of each column to 0.5. To subset rows, I have used `get` function.

Is this correct way of doing, or is there any other way, which is more aligned with data.table?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can use `set`

```
for(vrb in names(dataT)){
 set(dataT, i = which(dataT[[vrb]] < 0.5), j = vrb, value = 0.5)
}
```

The elements in the first column is > 0.5.  So, we can apply the `set` on columns except the first

```
for(vrb in names(dataT)[-1]){
  set(dataT, i = which(dataT[[vrb]] < 0.5), j = vrb, value = 0.5)
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

This may have a slight performance penalty for not subsetting first before the update, but I find it more readable:

```
dataT[, colnames(dataT) := lapply(.SD, pmax, .5)][]
```